# Javascript: How to attach methods to a already defined type

Tags: javascript, intern

I'm currently using "Intern.js" to do functional/behavior tests for my front-end application(click on buttons, expect a message to pop-up and so on).

A simple test would be something like:

```
bdd.describe('###### txtFirstName', function() {
  bdd.it('must be a "text" type input', function() {
    /** Begin the test */
    let test =

      /** Find the 'addUserModal' on the DOM and then find the 'txtFirstName' inside it */
      helper.addUserModal.find.field.txtFirstName()
        .getProperty('type')
        .then(function(type) {
          expect(type).to.equal('text');
        })
        .end()
    /** End the test */
    .end();

    return test;
  });
});
```

Note that this part of the test:

```
.getProperty('type')
.then(function(type) {
  expect(type).to.equal('text');
})
.end()
```

Would be repeated for every input on the modal, so  instead of repeating it on every test, I wanted to do something like:

```
/** Begin the test */
let test =
  /** Find the 'addUserModal' on the DOM and then find the 'txtFirstName' inside it */
  helper.addUserModal.find.field.txtFirstName()
    .must.be.a.text.input()
/** End the test */
.end();
```

And the "must.be.a.text.input()" would have the type assertions.

A important thing to notice is that all those "Intern.js" methods returns a Promise.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Thanks!

> The "Intern.js" lib:
>   https://theintern.github.io/
>
> It's documentation:
>   https://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/module-leadfoot_Command.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [chai-as-promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/).

With chai-as-promised, your code

```
helper.addUserModal.find.field.txtFirstName()
    .getProperty('type')
    .then(function(type) {
      expect(type).to.equal('text');
    })
```

can be written as

```
expect(helper.addUserModal.find.field.txtFirstName().getProperty('type'))
    .to.eventually.equal('text')
```